# Close and Open Another Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to write a script that will ask a word in English and then show its meaning. I am able to ask the question but the answer window doesn't show up. Code I wrote so far as below. In second window, it starts like a new page. How can I modify it? Now, it shows the label but buttons doesn't seem.

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        """Initialize the Frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.button_clicks = 0  # count the number of button clicks
        self.create_widgets()

    def root_close(self):
        global root
        root.destroy()
        self.button_clicky()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Button displays number of clicks"""
        if clicker % 2 == 0:
            self.soru = Label(self, text="Kelime: " + kelime)
            self.soru.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

            self.btn_submit = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.root_close)
            self.btn_submit.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
        else:
            self.cevap = Label(self, text="Kelimenin türkçe anlamları:\n" + anlam)
            self.cevap.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

            self.btn_okay = Button(self, text="Bildim", command=self.dogru)
            self.btn_submit.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

            self.btn_okay = Button(self, text="Bilemedim", command=self.yanlis)
            self.btn_submit.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

    def button_clicky(self):
        global clicker
        clicker += 1

    def dogru(self):
        #will do stuff
        self.root_close()

    def yanlis(self):
        self.root_close()


clicker = 0
kelime = "apple"
anlam = "elma"
root = Tk()
root.title("Ask word")
root.geometry("200x85")
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I get from your question is that you have the first window with the Kelime question, and you want to open up another window with the else clause in your `create_widgets()` function once you click the submit button. The problem here is that when you are running `root_close()`, you're essentially terminating the whole program (the program runs because the root is on a loop created by `root.mainLoop()`). If you want to open one window when you close the other, check out [Closing current window when opening another window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434654/closing-current-window-when-opening-another-window?rq=1)
.